# How to get my own Facebook user access token indefinitely?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I want to pull my most recent images from facebook's api for my personal website. I cannot seem to find a way to only authenticate my user without the login dialog. Does anyone know if this is possible? I can generate my user access token inside the graph API Explorer, but it expires in 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

> How to get my own Facebook user access token indefinitely

You **cannot**!

But you can [**extend**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending) this token that will be valid for **60 days** - called the *long-lived token*. So, if a user visits your application at least once in 60 days you can have the access to user's data indefinitely.

Simple call to get the long-lived user access token-

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Refreshing this token- The user have to go through the login process again (calling `login` API) to get the short-lived token and then perform the same exchange for a fresh long lived token with 60 days expiry.

You can also debug your token anytime with-

```
GET /debug_token?
    input_token={input-token}&    
    access_token={access-token}  // a valid user access token or app access token
```

Comment: I have already generated a long lived token, but I feel like there should be a way to access your personal photos via the api without having a login dialog. I don't want anyone else to login. I just want my photos from my user. Any ideas

Comment: His first statement was pretty clear: you can't.  Its designed to be this way.

Comment: You just have to click on a button (login) and some redirections will happen and a fresh token will be generated. See, if its only you why is this a problem? Anyways, that's be design and you cannot get one that you are looking for. If you have to post something on wall indefinitely - that you can do by using the `app-access-token`, but for photos you have to do what I've mentioned