# Facebook Graph Api extended user access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've been searching all over the place how to extend the user access token. I've found this site, but i don't want to share my access token with them (obviously). Can someone point me in the right direction?

https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/docs/get-extended-facebook-user-access-token/

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I want to get a user access token as well, but for my own admin user so that people visiting my website can see a feed from my closed facebook group.

Comment: I had to take a bite of that sour apple, and prepare myself to do a manual process every 60 days. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29059389/1471485

Answer (score 0):

The official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

And an additional link: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Btw, that tutorial in your question is really just a tutorial, they are using the API Explorer, which is an important tool made by Facebook.